# BlackBerry Facebook SDK jar file

Tags: java, blackberry, facebook

Hey people, I'm having a problem with the Facebook Blackberry SDK and how to use it in my project. I have a project made with the source files available on SourceForge and I referenced this project in the project I am developing, works just well for programming but when I want to deploy my app even on a simulator it will ask me to deploy the StrawBerry app that comes with it as well, even if I exclude it from the referenced project.

I tried making a jar file with the packages but i can't manage to use it on my project and am unable to preverify it i get jar file creation error -1. Has anyone done this? Or if anyone has used the SDK before how have you done it?

Comment: The thing is that it's a zip file not a JAR and i don't know how to include it inside my project, and i can't find any explanation on forums or even on the project site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I decided that what I was trying to do was way to small to use the FB SDK, so what I did is create a browserfield2 on a screen that redirects to the Facebook website making calls to their GraphAPI for authentication and permissions.

Comment: I am struggling to do the same.  I have tried FB SDK, but failed repeatedly.  As you suggested here, I want to try the browser field approach. Can you please tell me the steps to update user status in fb ?

Comment: Hello Nilan, as you can see this was a long time ago that I did this, but from what I recall it was the simple auth approach that is used for web auth on FB, after that I get the token from the URL of the browserfield and store it. All the calls are made by my server, that ran in Java, using the RestFB library.

Comment: @Vius, thanks for your reply. I will try the same. May be i have to understand the FB Auth architecture.